# Working directory doesn't exsits in mule 4

Tags: mule-component, anypoint-studio

i have a flow that is deployed to cloudhub from anypoint studio, while testing from cloudhub it is giving me the error as working directory specified doesn't exist. I have given  C drive location in write component. How can i make it work?, Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no C: drive at all in CloudHub. You should not assume any particular operating system features in a platform to which you have no access. The documented place you can use for temporary files is /tmp (https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deploying-to-cloudhub#worker_sizing).

Note that all files should be considered temporary in CloudHub, because it is an integration platform, not a file storage platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but got the solution to this. mule4 has a default working directory,
in the file connector you can mention ${mule.home}/app/${app.name} no need to create any of the variables as they are picked by default, i tried this for writing a file. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not a good practice to use the application directory to process files. See my previous solution for an alternative.